# How to jump to the same line in two huge text files?

Tags: python, parsing, text, bigdata

I am trying to use python to do some manipulations on huge text files, and by huge I mean over 100GB. Specifically, I'd like to take samples from the lines of the files. For example, let's say I have a file with ~300 million lines, I want to take just a million, write them to a new file and analyze them later to get some statistics. The problem is, I can't start from the first line, since the first fraction of the file does not represent the rest of it good enough. Therefore, I have to get about 20% into the file, and then start extracting lines. If I do it the naive way, it takes very long (20-30 minutes on my machine) to get to the 20% line. For example, let's assume again that my file has 300 million lines, and I want to start sampling from line 60,000,000th (20%) line. I could do something like:

```
start_in_line = 60000000
sample_size = 1000000
with open(huge_file,'r') as f, open(out_file,'w') as fo:
    for x in range(start_in_line):
        f.readline()
    for y in range(sample_size):
        print(f.readline(),file=fo)
```

But as I said, this is very slow. I tried using some less naive ways, for example the `itertools` functions, but the improvement in running time was rather slight.
Therefore, I went for another approach - random seeks into the file. What I do is get the size of the file in bytes, calculate 20% of it and than make a seek to this byte. For example:

```
import os
huge_file_size = os.stat(huge_file).st_size
offset_percent = 20
sample_size = 1000000

start_point_byte = int(huge_file_size*offset_percent/100)
with open(huge_file) as f, open(out_file,'w') as fo:
    f.seek(start_point_byte)
    f.readline()    # get to the start of next line
    for y in range(sample_size):
        print(f.readline(),file=fo)
```

This approach works very nice, **BUT!**
I always work with pairs of files. Let's call them R1 and R2. R1 and R2 will always have the same number of lines, and I run my sampling script on each one of them. It is crucial for my downstream analyses that the samples taken from R1 and R2 coordinate, regarding the lines sampled. For example, if I ended up starting sampling from line 60,111,123 of R1, I must start sampling from the very same line in R2. Even if I miss by one line, my analyses are doomed. If R1 and R2 are of exactly the same size (which is sometimes the case), then I have no problem, because my `f.seek()` will get me to the same place in both files. However, if the line lengths are different between the files, i.e. the total sizes of R1 and R2 are different, then I am in a problem.
So, do you have any idea for a workaround, without having to resort to the naive iteration solution? Maybe there is a way to tell which line I am at, after performing the seek? (couldn't find one...) I am really out of ideas at this point, so any help/hint would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to simultaneously use reads and lines is going to be really tricky (as you say, if lines are different sizes it gets super confusing). You therefore can't really "jump" to a line. Have you considered `zip`ping the two file handles and iterating over them line-by-line in parallel?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - That would be better than iterating on each file separately, but would still be much slower than using seek. So I'll do that only if I can't find any other solution.

Comment: Without having a fixed line size, I don't see how you can combine `seek` with an idea of which line you're on - this is one of the weaknesses of the file abstraction. The line iteration is slow because Python is (basically) looking for the next `\n` in a stream of characters.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Must you dump it into two files or can you move it into a DB? With a big data oriented DB, you can do these operations quickly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - OK, thanks. I'll see if anything else comes up.

Comment: @EddB - unfortunately, I get this files from outside, so I can't control the way they are stored, and getting them into a DB will cost me a lot of time (or am I wrong?)

Comment: @soungalo Sorry for the late reply. No, you're almost entirely correct. It takes time, and quite a lot because of their size, but it'll be quicker than a script. What I wanted to do was save up the time wasted writing it to disk as that's the greatest bottle neck here. Analyzing 100GB of sorted data is quick. For example, HP's Vertica is an analytical DB that may meet your needs. Defining the table according to your analytical requirement will tell it how to load the data into it which then, in turn, greatly affects performance. Check if you're allowed to stream into a DB instead of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so thanks for the interesting answers, but this is what I actually ended up doing:

First, I estimate the number of lines in the file, without actually counting them. Since my files are ASCII, i know that each character takes 1 byte, so I get the number of characters in, say, the first 100 lines, then get the size of the file and use these numbers to get a (quite rough) estimation of the number of lines. I should say here that although my lines might be of different length, they are within a limited range, so this estimation is reasonable.
Once I have that, I use as system call of the Linux `sed` command to extract a range of lines. So let's say that my file really has 300 million lines, and I estimated it to have 250 million lines (I get much better estimations, but it doesn't really matter in my case). I use an offset of 20%, so I'd like to start sampling from line 50,000,000 and take 1,000,000 lines. I do:

```
os.system("sed -n '50000000,51000000p;51000000q' in_file > out_file")
```

Note the `51000000q` - without this, you'll end up running on the whole file.

This solution is not as fast as using random seeks, but it's good enough for me. It also includes some inaccuracy, but it doesn't bother me in this specific case.
I'd be glad to hear your opinion on this solution.

Comment: If that solves your problem, cool. My suggestion about `head | wc` was intended to give you an offset to which your python program could seek, which is roughly equivalent. You don't really need to create the temporary file, at least if you have bash, since you could use process substitution on the command line for the python script. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines in each file can have different lengths, there is really no other way than to scan them first (unless there is some form of unique identifier on each line which is the same in both files).

Even if both files have the same length, there could still be lines with different lengths inside.

Now, if you're doing those statistics more than once on different parts of the same files, you could do the following:

- do a one time scan of both files and store the filepositions of each line in a third file (preferably in binary form (2 x 64bit value) or at least the same width so you can directly jump to the position-pair of the line you want, which you could calculate then).
- then just use those filepositions to access the lines in both files (you could even calculate the size of the block you need from the different filepositions in your third file).

When scanning both files at the same time, make sure you use some buffering to avoid a lot of harddisk seeks.

**edit**:

I don't know Python (I'm a C++ programmer), but I did a quick search and it seems Python also supports memory mapped files (mmap).

Using mmap you could speed things up dramaticly (no need to do a readline each time just to know the positions of the lines): just map a view on part(s) of your file and scan through that mapped memory for the newline (\n or 0x0a in hexadecimal). This should take no longer than the time it takes to read the file.

Comment: Thanks, but I usually do this once on every file that I get, so your suggestions do not fit my case. I came up with a different approach (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Unix files are just streams of characters, so there is no way to seek to a given line, or find the line number corresponding to a given character, or anything else of that form.

You can use standard utilities to find the character position of a line. For example,

```
head -n 60000000 /path/to/file | wc -c
```

will print the number of characters in the first 60,000,000 lines of `/path/to/file`.

While that may well be faster than using python, it is not going to be fast; it is limited by the speed of reading from disk. If you need to read 20GB, it's going to take minutes. But it would be worth trying at least once to calibrate your python programs.

If your files don't change, you could create indexes mapping line numbers to character position. Once you build the index, it would be extremely fast to seek to the desired line number. If it takes half an hour to read 20% of the file, it would take about five hours to construct two indexes, but if you only needed to do it once, you could leave it running overnight.

Comment: Thanks, but I usually do this once on every file that I get, so indexing will not be of much use for me. I came up with an approach rather similar to your suggestion though (see my answer).